# Can two normal random variables compare?

Tags: inequality, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} e^{as}dB_{s}\leq\int_{0}^{2} e^{as}dB_{s}$, is this true?

In my opinion,

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} e^{as}dB_{s}=\int_{0}^{1} e^{as}dB_{s}+\int_{1}^{2} e^{as}dB_{s}$ and $\int_{1}^{2} e^{as}dB_{s}\sim N(0,\frac{e^{2as}-e^{as}}{as})$.

where $B_{t}$ is a Brownian motion.
Thanks for all your help?

Comment: so your opinion is that it's false? (also what is $\sigma^2$?... you can compute it, or does it matter? )

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks. Please see the edited question again.

Comment: You are adding an independent centered normal variable, which can be both negative and positive.

Comment: That distribution you wrote down looks about right (I think you might have missed a factor of two in the variance, but I don't know that it's important.). So what's your conclusion? Why were you wondering if it was true in the first place?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Because I want to use the well known inequlity ( Chebyshev's sum inequality) $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}\leq \frac{1}{n}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k})(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k})$. So I should testify the monotonicity of $\int_{0}^{1} e^{as}dB_{s},\int_{0}^{3} e^{as}dB_{s},\int_{0}^{2} e^{as}dB_{s}$ and so on.

Comment: But your argument shows the inequality is not true.  The difference is normally distributed, thus can be positive or negative.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle P\bigg(\int_0^1e^{as}dB_s\le\int_0^2e^{as}dB_s\bigg)=P\bigg(\int_1^2e^{as}dB_s\ge 0\bigg)=1/2$, since $\int_1^2e^{as}dB_s\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\sigma^2>0$.

Comment: impressive of your answer.